# How to get URLs from inline-keyboard message? (Telethon)

Tags: telegram, telethon

As title says, I have a [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aDlF.png) containing Inline-keyboard with command and URL buttons.

I need a URL which is in a specific button.

PS : I've looked in the documentation and issues several times but there is only click command.
I want to print its URL.

Answer (score 1):

A [`Message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/objects-reference.html#message) has [`Message.buttons`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.buttons), which is "a list of lists of [`MessageButton`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.messagebutton.MessageButton), if any". Those buttons in turn have a [`MessageButton.url`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.messagebutton.MessageButton.url) property. To wrap it up:

```py
url = message.buttons[row][column].url
print(url)
```